# Wpf Listview not populating with sqlite

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I am trying to populate a listview from sqlite database. My code is

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=c:\MyProjects\SqliteTest\TestData.db"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SQLiteDataAdapter ad = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
            String str = "SELECT Name,Email FROM tblInfo";
            cmd.CommandText = str;
            ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ad.Fill(ds);
            myList.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            connection.Close();
        }
```

and the xaml code is like

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="myList" 
              Height="100" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Margin="10,10,0,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="300">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Email" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Email}"></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

There is no error but list is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the DataContext of the control to your DataSet.  You either need to set the ListView's ItemSource to the DataSet, or bind the ItemSource to the DataContext, e.g.

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding}  ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

Phil is right, but you can also change

```
 myList.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

to

```
 myList.ItemsSource= ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Answer (score -1):

Dataset does not have interfaces INotifyCollectionChanged and INotifyPropertyChanged. so the UI does not know that the dataset has been populated.

If the dataset is changed once, you could bind (initialize) only after dataset is populated.

else, you could create a collection and implement the interfaces.